# iOS StoreKit - in-App Purchase by App Login

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, storekit

This is the scenario for the application right now:

The application I am working on has it's own login service, i.e., the user can register on the app and login to it too.

A user logs into the application (by the application's credentials) and then gets options to buy any of the 10 books listed there. After the book is bought, it will be registered with his application's userID and every time the user logs in with the ID, on any device, he will have that book available.

Now, since in this scenario, a user should be able to purchase a book again and again (but with different app credentials), I am thinking of using the "consumable" product option and adding a condition in the application itself that checks what books the logged in user has bought and not display to them the books they have bought (again, by app-credentials). This way, the won't be able to buy the same book again.

Is that possible?

Please advise.

Comment: Have you finally found a solution ? This is a common issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you just don't want to let user buy the same book more than one time. If so, you just need to check on application start which books user has already purchased and then correct the list of available for purchase books removing from it already purchased.

Comment: Yes sure, but I wanted the app to be "itunes account" independent. If I make it a non-consumable and a user of my app buys a book from one ID and then logs into another ID (Application specific ID that authenticates on my server), he would not see that book again as it was a non-consumable and can be purchased only once with one iTunes ID.

This problem will not be there if I list the book as a consumable and then add the check in the application to hide the books that are already bought with that ID. 

That being said, my question is, will Apple approve the application if I do it this way?

Comment: I just don't want my app to get rejected and learn about it the hard way, that's all.

Comment: I don't see any reasons for Apple to reject your app with your way of purchase realization. Just keep the purchase info for your accounts on your server and everything will be ok.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to implement Non-consumable product where if user purchase any book from one device then it should be available to user on other device as well.Store Kit provides built-in support to restore non-consumable products on multiple devices.To restore transactions, your application calls the payment queue’s restoreCompletedTransactions method.

Comment: Consider this scenario: 
User has bought the book on one device with his iTunes credentials and is logged in to the app with his app-specific credentials. Now, to restore the book on other device, he will have to log in to the app with the app-specific credentials and then to the itunes account with his itunes credentials. It doesn't seem very convinient to me..

Comment: When user make any purchase he/she has to first login to your app and then to itunes, even if he is purchasing the book for the first time.Then why do you think its not convenient to do this when he is purchasing this on the second device?For user it will same as purchasing the book on second device.

Comment: If you really do not want that user purchase the same book again,and if you are using server in that case you can save the product id of the book for that user.When user login to your app, you can find it out what all product he has already purchased and block user from purchasing it again.